# if row empty not working mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to show different image if the other is empty but the below code isn't working for me. In this case I have empty row for image two and image three has image name.

What am I missing here?

```
    $stmt = $mydb->prepare("select * from images where username = ? order by id desc");
echo $mydb->error;
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username->username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
?>
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
if($row['image_two'] = '')
{
echo $row['image_three'];
}
}?>
```

Comment: please think about accepting a answer so the thread closes. Thanks!

Comment: @CristianCavalli Okay I did, as it always tells me to wait I then forget.

Comment: remember to be careful with loose comparisons (i.e. '==') Strict comparisons like '===' are generally better, although when dealing with what php considers to be null or empty use of the `empty()` function is generally more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double equals for comparison.

```
if($row['image_two'] == '')
```

Answer (score 3):

you should do it with the native PHP functions

```
if(empty($row['image_two']))
```

Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)